# FB App Invites - send to specific friends?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the FB iOS SDK to invite friends using AppInvites.

The flow in my app is: 
1) Show all their FB friends
2) If a friend is tapped does not currently have the app installed, we open the App Invites Dialogue.
3) Problem: the user then has to find that same friend again from the friend list.

**Is it possible to pre-populate the invite dialogue with the friend the user sleected in step 2?**

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter for it according to the docs, so i assume it is not possible to prepopulate the dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios#dialog_parameters